# Order by on ClientDataSet doesn't work

Tags: delphi, sql-order-by, delphi-xe2

I have a problem with `TClientDataSet`. On the `DataSet`, the `order by` clause of my SQL works fine, but when I use a `TClientDataSet`, the records appear in order of the database's `id` field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is in the [`TDataSetProvider`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.Provider.TDataSetProvider), not in the [`TClientDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TClientDataSet) itself.

Try setting the [`poRetainServerOrder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Datasnap.Provider.TProviderOption) flag to `True` in the [`TDataSetProvider.Options`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Datasnap.Provider.TDataSetProvider.Options) property:

> Signals that the client should not attempt to re-establish the default order by sorting the records in the data packet. **This prevents the client from changing the record order** because, for example, it is unable to duplicate the locale on the server.